# content scripts no longer injected into tabs opened with window.open()

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[this is a WTF is going on question]

If a window is opened via window.open() with options specifically enabling the address bar, etc. the extension's content script is automatically injected; and hence available to open a port and begin a dialogue with the extension (for it to open its GUI front-end, etc).

However, if a window is opened via window.open() with window options not enabling the address bar, the content script is not injected.

Previously, in the second scenario it was possible to invoke a function in the dev_tools console which sent a message that was intercepted by the content script, re-formatted as needed by the extension daemon which then opened the extension's front-end (the SDK for a library embedded in the Tab/application).

This used to be the only way to open the SDK from a 'panel' style window - right click and select inspect to open dev_tools / console, invoke the openSDK() function, and voila the SDK opens.  This procedure still works in Opera and Vivaldi but not Chrome.

Is there ANY way to assure that Google Chrome will actually inject the content script spec'd in the manifest?

Thank you,
most likely still dazed and confused,
Chrys

[Please don't tell me to always open a floating panel as a full window/tab and not a panel - the embedded library does not control what the application using that library does or does not do.]

Comment: It's either a bug in Chrome or in that extension. Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to make the question answerable.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In attempting to create an MCVE for illustration and retest, I had to reboot and Chrome was updated. Now the content script shows up regardless of the window.open() mechanism/window-type used.  Only FFox still has a problem - but that is only with the mobile/tablet psuedo-responsive design FFox semi-support  (oh, well).  Thank you - I did not mean to bother anyone with this - but I spent a long time before beating my head against the wall before posting